# how do you run "npm install" inside of a folder from chef?

Tags: node.js, npm, chef-infra, package.json

I am attempting to install a nodejs project from GIT via a chef script.  I am banging my head trying to get NPM INSTALL to run from inside of the installed projects directory and leveraging the included "package.json" that is coming from GIT.

I also tried dwith the deprecated NPM cookbook:

```
 18>> npm_package do
 19:    path node[:deploy_nodejs_from_git][:destination]
 20:    action :install_from_json
 21:  end
```

but that isn't working - and I don't know if it is worth the effort to make it work since it is deprecated:

```
[2015-05-15T08:50:25-04:00] ERROR: You must supply a name when declaring a npm_package resource
```

I have looked at the [nodejs cookbook](https://github.com/redguide/nodejs) - but that requires you to list out the packages and not defer to the package.json.

Is this not the right approach?  We are a small shop and being able to leverage the package.json and not have to replicate seems ideal.

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. You need a name for every Chef resource. `npm_package 'anything_you_like' do ...`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am using, pending the identification of a better altternative:

```
if node[:deploy_nodejs_from_git][:destination]
  path = node[:deploy_nodejs_from_git][:destination]
  cmd  = "npm install"
  execute "npm install at #{path}" do
    cwd path
    command cmd
  end
end
```

The entire recipe to install a nodejs project from a git repo (with a self signed ssl), and subsequently calling NPM INSTALL leveraging the underlying package.json:

```
ENV['GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY']="true"

directory node[:deploy_nodejs_from_git][:destination] do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end

git node[:deploy_nodejs_from_git][:destination] do
  repository node[:deploy_nodejs_from_git][:git_repo]
  action :sync
  revision  node[:deploy_nodejs_from_git][:branch]
end

if node[:deploy_nodejs_from_git][:destination]
  path = node[:deploy_nodejs_from_git][:destination]
  cmd  = "npm install"
  execute "npm install at #{path}" do
    cwd path
    command cmd
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the nodejs cookbook, I use the following:

```
nodejs_npm 'package.json' do
  path node['myappplication']['home']
  json true
 end
```

Good part : it uses the package.json and installs the NPMs.
Bad part : it never ends and my chef-client hangs, but I dont this this is related to the cookbook itself.